# Password is not being checked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, authentication

When I try to login it is only checking for the username and not the password. Whatever password I give it accepts it. If I echo the html as 1 in connect.php it works properly except that the redirect doesn't work

dataconnect.php

```
<?PHP
    @mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
    or die("could not connect to mysql");
    @mysql_select_db("login")or die("no database");
?>
```

index.php

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Animated Login</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $(".center").animate({
                   opacity: 100.0,
                   left: '+=800',
                   height: 'toggle'
               }, 5000, function(){
            });
            $(".sign_b_btn").live("click",function() {
                var u=$("#u").val();
                var p=$("#p").val();
                if(u==""){
                    $("#u").css("border-color","red");
                    $("#un").css("color","red");
                    $(".error").show().html("Please enter your username.");
                    $("#p").css("border-color","#606060");
                    $("#up").css("color","#333333");
                }else if(p==""){
                    $("#u").css("border-color","#606060");
                    $("#un").css("color","#606060");
                    $(".error").show().html("Please enter your password.");
                    $("#p").css("border-color","red");
                    $("#up").css("color","red");
                }else{
                    dataString = 'u=' + u + '&p=' + p;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "connect.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(html){
                            if(html == "" ){
                                $(".error").show().html("The email or password you entered ois incorrect.");
                                $("#p,#u").css("border-color","red");
                                $("#up,#un").css("color","red");
                            }if(html != ''){
                                var redirect_url = html;
                                $(".error").fadeOut(1000);
                                $("#u").css("border-color","#606060");
                                $("#un").css("color","#333333");
                                $("#p").css("border-color","#606060");
                                $("#up").css("color","#333333");
                                $(".center").animate({
                                   opacity: 0.25,
                                   left: '+=900',
                                   height: 'toggle'
                               }, 5000, function() {
                                   $(".done").slideDown(200).html("Welcome "+u); 
                                    setTimeout(function(){
                                        var u=$("#u").val("");
                                        var p=$("#p").val(""); 
                                        window.location=redirect_url;
                                    }, 5000);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        });
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="done"></div>
        <div class="center">
            <div class="title">Login</div>
            <div class="error"></div>
            <div class="input">
                <div class="left" id="un">Username:</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input type="text" class="log" id="u"></div><div class="c">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input">
                <div class="left" id="up">Password:</div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input type="password" class="log" id="p">
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="sign_b_btn">
                <div class="sign_btn">Sign In</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?PHP 
include('dataconnect.php');//Your connection to your database

//Get posted values from form
$u=$_POST['u'];
$p=$_POST['p'];

//Strip slashes
$u = stripslashes($u);
$p = stripslashes($p);

//Strip tags 
$u = strip_tags($u);
$p = strip_tags($p);

$p=md5($p);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u' 
AND pass='$p'")or die(mysql_error());
$check = mysql_num_rows($check);
if($check !== "0"){
$results = mysql_query("SELECT user, redirect FROM user WHERE user ='$u'") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $user=$row['user'];
    session_register('user'); 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
    echo $row['redirect'];
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "redirect doesnt work"?

Comment: Make the code aligned first.

Comment: 1) You don't have a redirect
2) @mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die("could not connect to mysql"); => Every error that passes by will be ignored because of the `@`

Comment: @BartłomiejWach This portion of the code doesn't work window.location=redirect_url; if I change echo = "1";

Answer (score 1):

I tried my best understanding your work, hope it helps.

From your query

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT user, redirect FROM user WHERE user ='$u'") or die(mysql_error());
```

On `WHERE` clause, you're only putting the username as your validation thing.

Try adding the password too.

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT user, redirect FROM user WHERE user ='$u' AND password ='$p'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: He check pass in line - 17

Comment: ok I corrected my mistake but now it shows error even for the correct password

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
if ($check !== "0") { ...
```

which is checking for a string, when `$check` is an integer. Change it to:

```
if ($check != "0") { ...
```

which  will check if `$check` is `0` in either string or integer form

or change it to

```
if ($check !== 0) { ...
```

which will check if `$check` is the integer `0` (which is what it would be)

Comment: I tried all of the above they always give the error message username or password is incorrect even for the correct entries in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with this:

```
if($check !== "0"){
```

`!==` is [strict comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), while `$check` will hold an *integer* value, you are comparing against the *string* `"0"` which do not result in equal *data type* and thus the `if` is never entered.. To correct it, you should do:

```
if($check > 0){
```

which means if the number of rows returned is greater than 1. If no combination with that *username* and *password* is found, it will result in 0 rows.

Comment: I tried it. It always give the error message username or password is incorrect even for the correct entries in the database.

Comment: @user2978016 Have you tried debugging? 1) Copy the query with the same values and try it on phpMyAdmin 2) I forgot to mention storing password as clear text is **highly** vulnerable

Comment: @user2978016 Save the query into a variable, echo it to see what values are passed and then try that value in your phpMyAdmin

Comment: I'm sorry I can't find a way to do this could you guide me how? I'm still learning

Comment: Try `$query="SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u' 
AND pass='$p'"; echo $query;` and strike that comment about password being stored as clear text, but `md5` is not safe anymore too, it's reversible if you didn't know.

Comment: so I just add these lines in place of $check?

Comment: @user2978016 It's really difficult to explain through little comments. Join [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) I'll explain.

Answer (score 0):

Check your return value in variable $check. if we have any values, then we can use next code.

```
if($check){
```

Try!

Comment: I tried it. It always give the error message username or password is incorrect even for the correct entries in the database.

Comment: Delete next line `//Strip slashes
$u = stripslashes($u);
$p = stripslashes($p);

//Strip tags 
$u = strip_tags($u);
$p = strip_tags($p);` and check

Comment: put into your query real pass and username `$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='Anton' 
AND pass='rdfqwj5tr8e5'");` and check `var_dump($check);` Maybe you have error in your string query.

Comment: var_dump($check); where do i write this?

Comment: After `$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user ='$u' 
AND pass='$p'")or die(mysql_error());`